# iOS: Stack objects on top of each other using NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I'd like to stack a few buttons on top of each other, and then show/hide them as a way to toggle. (Think a play/pause/replay button in a video player).

Is it possible to use NSLayoutConstraint to do this?

Alternatively, perhaps there's an even better way to create a multi-state button in iOS?

Here's what I tried, but obvoiusly doesn't work as it puts them next to eachother:

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_playButton][_pauseButton][_replayButton][_scrubber][_minimizeButton]|"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:viewsDictionary];
```

Using some tips from @dasdom below, I've come up with the following:

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_pauseButton]-[_scrubber]-[_minimizeButton]|"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:nil
                      views:viewsDictionary];

[constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_playButton]"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:nil
                      views:viewsDictionary]];

[constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_replayButton]"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:nil
                        views:viewsDictionary]];

[self addConstraints:constraints];
```

Which is really close - the spacing horizontally is correct, and for the items in the first rule (pauseButton, scrubber, minimize) they are aligned correctly vertically, but the play and replay button are too high... as if the subsequent `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY` is being ignored.

Edit2: Here's the final code I ended up with, took much more than I thought it would, but seems to work well:

```
NSDictionary *metrics = @{
    @"buttonPadding": @(kBarPaddingX)
};
// Align along Y center and set order, so scrubber stretches in the middle.
NSString *controlsVisualFormat =
  @"|-buttonPadding-[_playButton]-[_scrubber]-[_minimizeButton]-buttonPadding-|";
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:controlsVisualFormat
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:metrics
                      views:viewsDictionary];

// Set alignment of pauseButton and replayButton
constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-buttonPadding-[_pauseButton]"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:metrics
                      views:viewsDictionary]];
constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-buttonPadding-[_replayButton]"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:metrics
                        views:viewsDictionary]];

// Not sure why using NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY above doesn't center the buttons vertically,
// so we need another set of constraints to center them vertically.
constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_pauseButton
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:_pauseButton.superview
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              multiplier:1.0f
                                constant:0]];
constraints = [constraints arrayByAddingObject:
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_replayButton
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:_replayButton.superview
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              multiplier:1.0f
                                constant:0]];
```

Comment: I know you've accepted an answer, but are you sure your layout isn't ambiguous? Set a breakpoint in viewDidAppear:, then cut and paste the following in the debugger: po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace].

Comment: Yes, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Do you need to include `H:` and `V:` in front of your `contraintsWithVisualFormat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_playButton(==_pauseButton)]"
                  options:0
                  metrics:nil
                  views:viewsDictionary];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_playButton(==_pauseButton)]"
                  options:0
                  metrics:nil
                  views:viewsDictionary];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_playButton 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
    toItem:_pauseButton 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
    multiplier:1.0f 
    constant:0.0f]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_playButton 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
    toItem:_pauseButton 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
    multiplier:1.0f 
    constant:0.0f]];
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `_playButton` instead of `_infoButton` in those?

Comment: This code gave me some ideas to try, so I updated my code (see updated q). I just need to figure out the veritcal spacing of the play/replay buttons now. Any idea why the `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY` isn't working for those? They are higher than the other elements for some reason.

Comment: Gave you the answer, although it took a bit more code than this (see my 2nd edit!) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses the code under Edit2.

You did a good job building a nice horizontal row of various buttons, i.e., `_playButton` -> `_minimizeButton`. However, the format option `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY` only aligns each button vertically with respect to all the other buttons. You still haven't established a rule that positions the row of buttons along the vertical axis *with respect to the row's container view*.

Since all the buttons are already vertically aligned with respect to each other, all you have to do is add a vertical-axis type constraint to one of the buttons (any button). Here's a hypothetical example that pins the top of the play button 40 points from the top of the container view. If you want a more practical example, I would need to have a better understanding of the overall layout.

```
[[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_playButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:40.0f]];
```